# Peculiar problem with Wi-Fi

Tags: wireless

My wireless doesn't work like it should. I just installed Ubuntu 16.04 on a new machine dual boot with Windows 10 (previously I tried installing other Linux distros, but had the same problem).

Here's what happens: my laptop is plugged (power), then i turn it on and what happens is that with every linux distro the Wi-Fi doesn't work upon the start; i have to unplug and plug it again (always to the power) for the Wi-Fi to work. Then when I turn it off, the whole thing repeats.

Now, here's a couple of information you might want to know:

- The WiFi works just fine, all the time with Windows 10.
- During the installation of Antergos from Live USB, the WiFi works. Sometimes it can happen that the wifi works for a while, even though i restart it multiple times, but eventually, the wifi starts to do this strange thing.

  ```
  $ lspci -knn | grep -iA2 net
  02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros QCA9565 AR9565 Wireless Network Adapter [168c:0036] (rev 01)    
  Subsystem: Lite-On Communications Inc QCA9565 / AR9565 Wireless Network Adapter [11ad:0642] 
  Kernel driver in use: ath9k Kernel modules: ath9k 

  $ rfkill list 
  0: phy0: Wireless LAN 
     Soft blocked: no 
     Hard blocked: yes 
  1: acer-bluetooth: Bluetooth 
     Soft blocked: no 
     Hard blocked: no 
  2: hci0: Bluetooth 
     Soft blocked: no 
     Hard blocked: no
  ```

Comment: Typing Rfkill in the terminal shows that the Wi-Fi is hard blocked;
Typing "cat /sys/class/rfkill/rfkill0/hard" i get the result "1", but when i try to change it, i get permission denied. (even as root; "sudo -i")

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2; rfkill list` terminal command.

Comment: Have you tried to add the driver name to /etc/modules? Cheers, Al

Comment: For the rfkill command, try `sudo rfkill unblock all`. Also, assure that you don't have a wi-fi hardware switch in the off position. Cheers, Al

Comment: @pilot6 This is the result: 02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: 
```
Qualcomm Atheros QCA9565 / AR9565 Wireless Network Adapter [168c:0036] (rev 01)
 Subsystem: Lite-On Communications Inc QCA9565 / AR9565 Wireless Network Adapter [11ad:0642]
 Kernel driver in use: ath9k
 Kernel modules: ath9k
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
 Soft blocked: no
 Hard blocked: yes
1: acer-bluetooth: Bluetooth
 Soft blocked: no
 Hard blocked: no
2: hci0: Bluetooth
 Soft blocked: no
 Hard blocked: no
```

Comment: @heynnema I tried to unblock all but nothing happened. The pshysical button is okay.

Note: When i unplug it the wifi does NOT go away, so i don't think it's a power management problem (it's off)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run in terminal

```
sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-acer-wmi.conf <<< "blacklist acer_wmi"
```

and reboot.

Comment: Thank you so very much! I have rebooted the laptop a couple of times and so far the wi fi is working! Thank you again! One last question: Does that code work on other linux distros? I'm asking because sometimes Antergos didn't recognize the "Sudo" command.

Comment: It should work on all distros. It is only kernel related. But not all distros have sudo.